# Capturar Datos en JS y Pasarlos a PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Quiero pasar los datos que recibo en los parametros de una funcion JS e imprimirlos en PHP:

```
$autodoc = $fila['AUTODOC'];
$autolin = $fila['AUTOLIN'];
$autofue = $fila['AUTOFUE'];
```

A través de del evento onclick llevo los parametro a la funcion

```
echo "<td>";
echo "<button  name='nombre' type='submit' class='btn btn-success' onclick='accion( \"{$autofue}\", \"{$autodoc}\", \"{$autolin}\");'>  AUTORIZAR</button>";
echo "</td>";
```

//funcion JS

```
function accion(a, b, c){
alert(a+' '+b+' '+c);
<?php 
echo "<p>'{a}'</p>"; // imprimir el parametro que recibo de JS en esta linea
$stid =  oci_parse($conn, "DELETE FROM TAB_AUTO 
where autofue='IN'
and autodoc='1017951'
and autolin= 1"); 
oci_execute($stid); ?>
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero es que hay que separar las aguas.
PHP se ejecuta en el lado del servidor y JS en el lado de Cliente (considerando las excepciones)

Sabiendo esto, lo que te recomiendo es hacer lo siguiente.

Deduciendo, según tu código, que estas seleccionado un registro el cual lleva el id de algo que deseas eliminar, tendrias que enviar este `ID` a un controlador en PHP, mediante AJAX (de javascript)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const autofue = jQuery('#nombre').data('autofue');
        const autodoc = jQuery('#nombre').data('autodoc');
        const autolin = jQuery('#nombre').data('autolin');
        const data = { 
            "autofue": autofue,
            "autodoc": autodoc,
            "autolin": autolin,
            };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'controlador.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log(response)
           }
       });
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" id="form">
<button name='nombre' id="nombre" type='submit' class='btn btn-success' data-autofue="{$autofue}" data-autodoc="{$autodoc}" data-autolin="{$autolin}"> AUTORIZAR</button>
</form>
```

Luego, en el `controlador.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['autofue']) && $_POST['autofue'] && isset($_POST['autodoc']) && $_POST['autodoc'] && isset($_POST['autolin']) && $_POST['autolin']) {
    $autofue = $_POST['autofue'];
    $autodoc = $_POST['autodoc'];
    $autolin = $_POST['autolin'];
    $stid =  oci_parse($conn, "DELETE FROM TAB_AUTO where autofue='".$autofue."' and autodoc='".$autodoc."' and autolin=".$autolin."); 
    oci_execute($stid);
    echo "Registro eliminado con éxito";
} else {
    echo "No ha llegado el identificador";
}
```

Entonces, cuando tu controlador procese, lo que quieras hacer, restornará un mensaje el cual será recibido por el `success` de tu javascript

```
success: function(response)
         {
            console.log(response)
          }
```

Comment: Los datos los estoy obteniendo de un boton con el evento onclick, no provienen de ningun input de formulario, los datos provienen de la DB de oracle y lo que hago es capturarlos en ese evento para luego eliminarlos:

 `echo "<button  name='nombre' type='submit' class='btn btn-success' onclick='accion( \"{$autofue}\", \"{$autodoc}\", \"{$autolin}\");'> AUTORIZAR</button>";`

Comment: No necesito redirrecionar a ninguna pagina lo que quiero es que se ejecute el Delete, luego pondria un refresh a la pagina.

Comment: Justamente al hacerlo con ajax, no estas redirigiendo a ninguna pagina, y el "refresh" lo haria una vez llegue el valor al `success`

Answer (score 0):

eso que quieres hacer no es normal o no esta bien, ademas tu php no tiene ningun valor del JS, puedes ser mas especifico si la funcion viene de un formulario (de un boton submit).

Saludos!

Comment: Viene de una tabla en html, la idea es que a través del evento onclick pueda capturar 3 datos que voy a pasar luego a la consulta que esta en la funcion para que se eliminen:
`$autodoc = $fila['AUTODOC'];
$autolin = $fila['AUTOLIN'];
$autofue = $fila['AUTOFUE'];


echo "<td>";
echo "<button  name='nombre' type='submit' class='btn btn-success' onclick='accion( \"{$autofue}\", \"{$autodoc}\", \"{$autolin}\");'> AUTORIZAR</button>";
echo "</td>";`